# How disable days (by date) in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I use the current latest fullcaldendar.io (v6.1.4) library in javascript. I can disable days (grey out) by date range (startdate to stopdate) in month view.

My Question: How i can disable specific single days like as example 2023-03-18 and 2023-03-23 in month view? The day in monthview should be grayed out and disable onclick events for this day.

I can‘t found this informations in the fullcalendar documentation.

Comment: If you want to disable specific days rather than a range, usually the best thing to do is use a separate event feed and deliver the days as background events (these are mentioned in the docs). You can then add contraints via the various "select..." callbacks (selectConstraint, selectAllow etc) to disallow selection when the selected area overlaps with one of these background events. Pretty sure this has been asked before, somewhere in the archives of stackoverflow, but I couldn't find it right now

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called selectAllow

```
  selectAllow={function (span, mov) {
      if (canEdit(span.startStr)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        notification.open({ message: "You can't add here", type: "info", duration: 2 });
        return false;
      }
    }}
```

Here is my canEdit code

```
  function canEdit(cellDate: string) {
     cellDate += moment().format("[T]hh:mm:ss");
     return moment(cellDate).isBetween(
     moment(timeframeToEdit.start, "YYYY-MM-DD[T]hh:mm:ss"),
     moment(timeframeToEdit.end, "YYYY-MM-DD[T]hh:mm:ss")
     );
  }
```